# How to modify MATE Tweaks -> Appearance Preferences -> Fonts sizes through a script in command line

Tags: command-line, fonts, display-resolution, ubuntu-mate, appearance

Hi everyone and thank you for any help or advice that you could give me.

I work half time from home and half time in person in my office; however, the screen size/resolution of my available monitor at home (24", 1920 x 1080) vs at work (27", 3840 x 2160) are very different. The problem occurs when I open my session from home (I use NoMachine or X2Go to see the desktop), because everything is so small. What I do is to change the resolution of the screen (3840... -> 1920...), but then the font size of everything is gigantic, so I reduced the font sizes with MATE Tweaks - Appearane Preferences -> Fonts. That works perfectly while I am at home, but then, when I come to the office, all the Fonts are now too small to read and changing the resolution doesn't help, so I need to return the Font sizes back to the original. As I have to do this each time that I access the computer from a different place, I was wondering if it is possible to create a script that would change the Fonts to the preferred setting, and that way I just need to open the command line, run the appropriate script (ex: FontSize4Office.sh vs FontSize4Home.sh) and continue with my work.

Is it possible? Is there another solution? Am I overly complicating something that should be easy to do another way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can script this with `dconf`. I don't know which font you want to change, but here is an example:

```
dconf write "/org/mate/desktop/interface/font-name" "'Ubuntu Light 10'"
```

Easiest is to use `dconf-editor` to find the settings you need.

Comment: This works really nice but it only affects the Application Font. How can I modify the other ones too?: Document font, Desktop font, etc.

Comment: Search for "font" in `dconf-editor`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I want to thank Marco for his response. It helped me solve it. At the end, it was more difficult for me to use dconf as I do not have admin rights in my workstation and dconf-editor is not present. So instead, I ended up using `gsettings`. To modify the size of each different font (and also the font itself if you want to), I used the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.mate.interface font-name 'Ubuntu Regular 6.5' #Application font
gsettings set org.mate.interface document-font-name 'Ubuntu Regular 6.5' #Document font
gsettings set org.mate.interface monospace-font-name 'Ubuntu Regular 8' #Fixed-width font
gsettings set org.mate.Marco.general titlebar-font 'Ubuntu Medium 6.5' #Window title font
gsettings set org.mate.caja.desktop font 'Ubuntu 6.5' #Desktop font
```

I also added the selection of the proper terminal profile, so the command is this one:

```
gsettings set org.name.terminal.global default-profile "profile1"
```

If you want to see what are your current settings, use `get` instead of `set` in the commands.

If you want to know the commands through `dconf`, here they are:

```
dconf write "/org/mate/desktop/interface/font-name" "'Ubuntu Regular 6'"
dconf write "/org/mate/desktop/interface/document-font-name" "'Ubuntu Regular 6'"
dconf write "/org/mate/caja/desktop/font" "'Ubuntu 6'"
dconf write "/org/mate/marco/general/titlebar-font" "'Ubuntu Medium 6'"
dconf write "/org/mate/desktop/interface/monospace-font-name" "'Ubuntu Mono Regular 8'"
```